# Создание регистрации на сайте

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Установил сервер по вот этой инструкции: [Установка сервера Apache, MySQL и PHP интерпретатора](http://ab-w.net/PHP/server_set.php). Теперь не знаю, как создать регистрацию и что делать дальше. Помогите, очень нужно. В программировании не новичок, если что, пойму.

Comment: Не совсем понял: в программировании не новичок, но регистрацию сделать не можете?

Comment: Я прост веб-программированием никогда не занимался. Изучил c#, смотря на js что-то понимаю а что-то нет! А то как описывают некоторые сайты вообще пугает и непонятно как работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Создание регистрации на сайте на PHP + MySQL](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=347).

Comment: Только из соображений безопасности в БД лучше отправлять md5($password)

Answer (score 1):

Если самому писать не хочется/не получается, можно выбрать из [готового](http://www.vanta.ru/script/catalog.php?cat=50&clas=0)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь описано всё более подробно: [Создание регистрации на сайте на PHP + MySQL](http://antvo.ru/php/20-sozdanie-registracii-na-sayte-na-php-mysql.html).

Answer (score 0):

Сессии + Бд(MySQL)